# Inserting in PostgreSQL Foreign Table Violates Primary Key Constraint10

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, postgresql-9.5

I  have two local databases in one of them I have created a foreign table that is referencing a table in the second database. When I want to insert in foreign table it inserts the primary key all over from beginning from 1 although when I insert in the actual table it continues from the last value entered.
Is there any way so if I insert in actual or foreign table it goes on the sequence of primary key?

```
CREATE TABLE Actual_Table (
  id   serial   PRIMARY KEY
  name varchar
);
```

Then I insert some data in the actual table

```
INSERT INTO Actual_Table (name) VALUES
  ('AHMAD'),
  ('MAHMOOD');
```

Then I create the following foreign table in the second database

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE Foreign_Table (
  id serial,
  name varchar
) server some_server options(schema_name 'public', table_name 'Actual_Table')
```

And then when I user insert in foreign table using the following insert statement I get an error that is violating the primary key constraint

```
INSERT INTO Foreign_Table (name) VALUES ('John');
```

This is the error I get

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "to_copy_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
CONTEXT:  Remote SQL command: INSERT INTO public.to_copy(id, name) VALUES ($1, $2)
```

Comment: Does it work if you create the foreign table with `integer` instead of `serial`?

Comment: No, it still starts from 1 which is already in the column

Comment: Then the sequence on the foreign table is out of sync with the underlying values in the table.

Comment: exactly, how can we sync them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/244243/330315

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you ignore ID field in the Foreign_Table script and try inserting? It should use the current serial value in the Foreign Table.

```
{
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE Foreign_Table (name varchar) server 
    some_server options(schema_name 'public', table_name 'Actual_Table')
}
```